# Revert ip command without rebooting server

Tags: ip, ipv6

My VPS provider told me to execute this command for solving an issue with IPv6, but now the server is unreachable using IPv6 and support service will work tomorrow after 0900 GMT

How can I revert this command without rebooting the server?

```
ip -6 neigh replace fe80::1 lladdr 28:99:3a:4d:23:91 dev eth0 nud permanent
```

Comment: There is not enough data to answer your question. Please add details about the interfaces and the ipv6 configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used the permanent parameter you can only revert manually by deleting the same entry.

```
ip -6 neighbour delete fe80::1 lladdr 28:99:3a:4d:23:91 dev eth0 nud permanent
```

I am not aware of why your VPS provider is telling you to do this if IPv6 was accessible before.

To get back to an autoconfigured state without restarting type

```
ip -6 neighbour flush

ip -6 neighbour
```

That gets you stateless IPv6. If its still not getting an IP try

```
dhclient -6
```

If that doesn't work you need more information from your VPS provider.